# Analytics not working in Chrome App

Tags: google-analytics, google-chrome-app

I am trying to add Google Analytics to a Chrome App using the google-analytics-bundle.js library found [here](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/chrome-platform-analytics). Apart from the example in the bundle itself I also tried this [sample](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/chrome-app-samples/tree/master/samples/analytics) with no success.

Note that the tracking ID in both tests was been replaced to my own property id, which has already been used successfully before with a separate website.

Here's a screen shot which shows the details of the request and the data being sent:

[image: analytics request details]

Comment: How do you know it's not working?

Comment: I have checked the real time tab and I am not seeing any active user .. if I use the same tracking code from a regular web page it works.

Comment: You need a "Mobile app" type of tracking ID, not a Website type. If you say that the same code works from a web page - maybe you're using the wrong type?

Comment: That solved the problem I was not aware there were two different types of tracking id... Thanks

Comment: I'll post it as an answer then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you said that the same tracking ID works on a website, it probably means that you have a wrong *kind* of tracking ID.

From the Wiki of the library:

> ### Prerequisites
>
> [...]
>
> - get a Google Analytics ["App" tracking property](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2614741).

There are 2 types of properties, selected at property creation: "Website" and "Mobile App". You need the second type to work in a Chrome App.